# Database abstraction for creating tables/views in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, database-abstraction, database-table

I'm wondering if there is a solution for creating database models (tables and views) independend from the used DBMS. I'm using Zend Framework at the moment and the abstraction for the basic CRUD operations is really great, but it doesn't provide the abstraction for creating tables and views. I know some ORM Frameworks provide this functionality, but sadly it's not possible to use an ORM in my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don`t know about ZF2, but in ZF there is no abstraction for creating tables.

If you change your mind about `not possible` I can advise you doctrine2

Comment: Doctrine is a cool solution here -- it could migrate your schema changes and many-many other things. Why is you don't want/can't use ORM??

Comment: Because I'm talking about an already existing big application, where it would be very time intensive to change it to an ORM, the other thing is that it has to be backward compatible and some operations are simple not possible (or just too slow) with an ORM.

Comment: So.. there is only one way - write our own implementation